# Can JavaFX natively show OS notifications?

Tags: java, javafx, notifications

AWT's `TrayIcon` class has a method called [`displayMessage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TrayIcon.html#displayMessage(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.awt.TrayIcon.MessageType)) that shows a native OS message that in Windows 10 looks like this:

[image]

as a pop up and like this:

[image]

in the notification area.

Can JavaFX do this natively? I know JavaFX doesn't implement traybar support yet and one has to use AWT, but are these notifications traybar dependent?

Comment: `ControlsFX` has something similar,

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question and specifically what "traybar dependent" notifications mean.  You can use [awt classes to show tray notifications for JavaFX classes](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/e231e89e8d36ef4e5d8a), as you already seem to know as indicated in your question.  There is an [unactioned feature request (JDK-8092115)](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8092115) for direct JavaFX API support for system tray functionality.

Comment: Wow, 94k rep just mainly from questions, that's wicked, never seen that before :-) kudos...

Comment: @jewlsea what I meant is that even though JavaFX doesn't implement traybar support, it could still implement these notifications as they are independent of the traybar. I was just preempting someone pointing out that there's no traybar support in JavaFX as a reason why you need to use AWT for notifications.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently javaFx Still doesn't provide way to show tray notifications, but you can use 3rd party library to achieve your goal .

[TrayNotification](https://github.com/PlusHaze/TrayNotification)

```
    String title = "Congratulations sir";
    String message = "You've successfully created your first Tray Notification";

    Notification notification = Notifications.SUCCESS;
    TrayNotification tray = new TrayNotification(title, message, notification);
    tray.showAndWait();
```

[image]

*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*

[ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/)

```
Notifications.create()
              .title("Title Text")
              .text("Hello World 0!")
              .showWarning();
```

[image]

Comment: But those do not use the OS notifications, do they?

Comment: you are correct, both of them use their own dialogs with transition

Comment: I'll accept this answer as the first sentence really answer my questions of "No, this is not possible yet". I personally think that using AWT for native OS notifications is a bit better than custom ones, but debating that was not the goal of the question. Maybe one day we'll update this once JavaFX implements it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @aKilleR.

Comment: @Pablo indeed, I also prefer AWT native popup until oracle comes up with new FX one , And thank u too

Comment: This is driving me insane. The AWT tray notifications make the tray [icon not receive click events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50278371/why-does-javas-awts-tray-icon-swallow-events-when-displaying-a-message), the ControlsFX one doesn't work if there's no visible stage, the TrayNotification doesn't seem to have been released.

Comment: sadly we have to keep an eye on [JDK-8092115](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8092115)

Comment: With Oracle discontinuing support and further development of JavaFX, we'll see if the community does anything, but I'm not keeping my hopes up.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming to this question in 2020, here's a stab at showing native OS notifications working with JavaFX:

https://gist.github.com/wiverson/d2edf0d66ad195c96793d0d25290753b

As noted in the sample, OS native notifications are best if the app is in the background - use ControlsFX notifications if the app is in the foreground.

This works on macOS Big Sur, should also work on Windows.

[Edit 1/5/21] Here is a project that also will help with this:

https://github.com/dustinkredmond/FXTrayIcon

Comment: Please note, SystemTray (where this is based on) is different from notification/messaging in Windows and GTK/Linux.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need any 3drparti libraries.

you can use **osascript** and **display** in the mac.

```
// java version
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "osascript", "-e", "display notification \"Message\" with title \"Title\"" });

// koltin version
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(arrayOf("osascript", "-e", "display notification \"Message\" with title \"Title\""))
```

Comment: This answer is for mac, but the asker's OS is windows, and for java it is preferable to have a cross-platform solution.